# Trying to make a Python 3 prime number generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

As the title suggests, I am attempting to make a Python 3-powered prime number generator and I can't get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
import random
def main():
    d=1
    x=random.randint
    while True:
        d=d+1
        if isinstance(x/d, int)==True:
            print (x)
        else: main()
main()
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/mint/casper-rw/ProjectsOrWork/Python/PrimeIdle.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/mint/casper-rw/ProjectsOrWork/Python/PrimeIdle.py", line 7, in main
    if isinstance(x/d, int)==True:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'int'
```

Comment: So I posted you code as well as suggestions/criticisms.

Answer (score 2):

Code is at bottom, but try to code your own based on the following suggestions, that's more educational for you:

1. `x = random.randint` is not actually calling `randint()`
2. You want to keep generating integer candidates and testing for primality. You should do this in a while-loop, not by recursing into `main()` every single time your candidate tests composite. That would cause unbounded stack growth and eventually overflow. (Never make a recursive call if you know you won't return from it). Also, you can't easily `return` from a very deep chain of recursion... you're kludging by using `print(x)` to sidestep that.
3. For all those reasons, and good decomposition, partition this into a generator called `generate_divisor()` and a predicate function `is_prime()` (that returns True/False).
4. Your main loop: here's how to make it non-recursive, and turn it into a while loop. For any integer x, you only need to test divisibility by (prime) divisors up to floor(sqrt(x)). If it isn't divisible by any of those divisors, it's prime, so `is_prime()` falls-through and returns True.
5. Your test for divisibility: `if (isinstance(x/d, int)==True)` is bad, beware truncation errors on large x/d, use `if (x%d == 0)` to test for divisibility instead.
6. Minor: you can easily get 60% performance boost on your prime sieve by observing that for d>5, primes can only end in 1,3,7 or 9. Hence don't do `d = d+1` (or `d += 1`), you're generating lots of composite divisors and diminishing few primes. (Indeed you're generating tons of composite divisors like 27 or 51, then testing divisibility by those, which is a total waste of time, since you already tested divisibility by 3 and 17.)

.

```
import random
from math import sqrt, floor

def generate_prime_candidate():
    """Generator to generate random prime candidate"""
    yield random.randint() # probably do randint(2, 2**32 -1). You decide.

def find_random_prime():
    x = generate_prime_candidate()
    while not is_prime(x):
        x = generate_prime_candidate()
    # Found one!
    print(x)
    return x

def is_prime(x):  # normally we call integers n, floats x, but whatever...
    for d in generate_divisors(floor(sqrt(x))): # only search up to sqrt(x)
        if x%d == 0:
            return False # x is composite - d is a divisor
        return True  # x is prime

def generate_divisors(dmax):
    """Generate divisors, up to a limit. We exclude numbers easily known to be composite: residue 0,2,4,5,6,8 modulo 10"""
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield 5 # now for d>5, exclude them by residue
    d = 7
    while d<dmax:
      while (d%10) == 5: # d easily known to be composite
        d += 2 # in fact we only need to test [0,2,4,6,8] not 5, since d+=2 is skipping residue 5 anyway
      yield d
```

Comment: #4: it isn't just bad; it won't work. It is always `True` in Python 2.x and always `False` in 3.x.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, 2-to-3 version difference, thanks. So what's the correct 3.x idiom for testing divisibility?

Comment: `x % d` is fine - my point is that integer division in Python 2.x means that `isinstance(x/d, int)` is `True` for all values of `x` and `d`, and in 3.x e.g. `4 / 2 == 2.0` (not `2`) so it's always `False`.

Comment: Oh, right. It's easier to test residue x%d == 0 than quotient x/d -is-an-integer.

Comment: In your `generate_divisors`, `while (d%10) in [0,2,4,5,6,8]` === `while (d%2 != 0) && d%5 != 0)`. But then for `d=7 ... d+=2`, `d%2 != 0` is always true. Then, testing `d%5 != 0` to spare `x%d == 0` is no gain at all...

Comment: @WillNess: yeah, strictly we only need test d%5!=0. The even residues are all excluded by design since we started with d=7. (You are correct that testing d%5 != 0 to spare making the division x%d == 0 is no gain at all, but I was hoping the OP would get the idea and generalize `generate_divisors(dmax)` to `generate_prime_divisors(dmax)`, in which case it does matter. Anyway we would probably use a caching decorator and save the known prime divisors in a set. So in the general sense, it would definitely make a difference. The second time through that function, it would fly along.)

Comment: correct; and then we don't need d%5 either, because there's no gain in using it: we can omit it here and this will add one more x%d there, in `find_random_prime`. going d=7, d+=2, just enumerates all odds, excluding the evens by construction. You can exclude the multiples of 3 too - but to do so by testing is pointless as we just saw. It must be so *by construction*. So how can this be done?.... :)

Comment: Like I wrote, **I was hoping the OP would get the idea and generalize `generate_divisors(dmax)` to `generate_prime_divisors(dmax)`, in which case it definitely does matter (for performance)**

Comment: But a fast-and-dirty construction to only get residues 1,3,7,9 is (starting from d=7) to yield `d += 2, d += 2, d += 2, d += 4`

Answer (score 1):

```
x=random.randint
```

doesn't assign a random integer to `x`, it assigns *the `randint` function*. You should do:

```
x = random.randint(min, max)
```

However, that is the least of your problems - your prime test won't work, that isn't actually a generator function and you pick a new random number on each recursive call.

Comment: Both 0 and 1 are 'undefined' for primality. You want to start at 2.

Comment: @chicken4thewin You can't do infinity, and you don't want to. Try 2**32 or 2**64. With this algorithm, your runtime for large x will be unbounded (days), also with very large x your recursion into main() will cause stack overflows as I noted below. Also you'll get false-negatives due to your divisibility test `isinstance(x/d, int)==True`, which won't work. See my comments on improving correctness and performance.

Comment: @chicken4thewin what are you trying to achieve, exactly? It might help to guide us to the best solution for you.

Comment: He(/She)'s trying a very crude prime sieve. See Sieve of Eratosthenes. Except he tries every single divisor d=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... , not just the prime ones.

Comment: @smci are you sure? What is the `random` element for, then?

Comment: Yes, I've seen a billion prime sieves. The only twist is he uses `random.randint()` to keep generating random integer candidates, then sieving them and rejecting them if they test composite by recursing into main() - which is far worse than just the the while-loop I describe. Ultimately for large x the unbounded recursion will cause stack overflows.